# maven - Plugin configuration not covered by lifecyle

Tags: maven, openhab

I am developing a binding for the smart home platform openHAB. As mentioned in the docs, I forked the main project and created a new branch and imported the new related project (see picture of my IDE below, the project with the "X").

I was surprised that my new project was creating some errors, which seem to be related to maven. I have no idea where to look to solve this issue.

[image]

**UPDATE:** due to some advice I used my systems maven version and the logs are telling me, that this is probably the main problem:

> [ERROR] The build could not read 1 project -> [Help 1]
> org.apache.maven.project.ProjectBuildingException: Some problems were encountered while processing the POMs:
>
> [ERROR] 'modules.module[181]' specifies duplicate child module org.openhab.binding.cus @ org.openhab.binding:pom:[unknown-version], E:\joba\workspace-openhab\OpenHabAddonDev\openhab-master\git\openhab2-addons\addons\binding\pom.xml, line 201, column 13
> at org.apache.maven.project.DefaultProjectBuilder.build (DefaultProjectBuilder.java:383)
> at org.apache.maven.graph.DefaultGraphBuilder.collectProjects (DefaultGraphBuilder.java:414)

Answer (score 0):

These are issues related to m2e (The Maven plugin in Eclipse). It tries to mimick Maven which does not work for not-so-standard Maven plugins. Usually, you can repair this by setting the policy to "ignore".